# Unresolved external Symbol, fatal error LNK1120

Tags: c++, fatal-error

I'm trying to create a program that stores an inventory of items into a dynamic array, while keeping track of the itemID, a description of the item, quantity and price. Only problem is I get an unresolved external symbol error

```
"struct inventory item * * list", fatal error LNK1120.
```

Any idea what the problem is or how to resolve it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct inventoryitem{
    char itemid[7];
    string itemDesc;
    int quantity;
    float price;
    float retailprice;
};

inventoryitem *list[];
void add();
void edit();
void search();
void display();
void remove();
void textfile();

int main(){//main menu
    while(true){
        cout << "\nInventory Database Manager\n";
        cout << "_____________________________\n";
        cout << "What would you like to do?\n";
        cout << "1) Add item to database\n";
        cout << "2) Edit item in database\n";
        cout << "3) Search the database for an item\n";
        cout << "4) Delete an item in database\n";
        cout << "5) Display all items\n";
        //cout << "6) Exit program\n";
        cout << "Input command (1-5)\n\n";
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        switch(input){
            case 1: add();
            case 2: edit();
            case 3: search();
            case 4: remove();
            case 5: display();
            default : cout << "\nError, invalid input, try again";
        }
    }
}

int inc = 0;

void add(){
    inventoryitem item;
    cout << "\nEnter Item ID (3 letters followed by 4 digits)\n";
    cin >> list[inc]->itemid;
    for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++){//validates the item ID, checks if the first 3 digits are numbers first, then the next 4 
        if(x < 2){
            if(isalpha(item.itemid[x])){
                //do nothing
            }
            else{
                cout << "Error, itemID is 3 letters followed by 4 digits";
                break;
            }
        }
        if(x > 2){
            if(isdigit(item.itemid[x])){
                //do nothing
            }
            else{
                cout << "Error, itemID is 3 letters followed by 4 digits";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Enter the item's description\n";
    cin >> list[inc]->itemDesc;
    cout << "Enter the quantity of item\n";
    cin >> list[inc]->quantity;
    cout << "Enter the price of the item\n";
    cin >> list[inc]->price;
    cout << "Enter the retail price of the item\n";
    cin >> list[inc]->retailprice;


}
void edit(){}
void search(){}
void display(){}
void remove(){}
void textfile(){}
```

Comment: Seems to me like your problem is that you don't actually instantiate your list anywhere... Though I find it odd that's a link error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) issues a more useful *compiler* error for this line:

```
inventoryitem *list[];
```

> definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer

In C++, you would be better to use one of the many [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) available to you. E.g:

```
std::list<inventoryitem>
```